# What is Perl's equivalent to PHP's print_r()?

Tags: php, perl, debugging

I find print_r in PHP extremely useful, but wonder if there is anything remotely equivalent in Perl?

Comment: When looking for equivalent functions, it's generally a good idea to explain what the original does. Not every Perl programmer is going to know what PHP's print_r() function does.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Note @tchrist recommends [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.21/lib/Data/Dump.pm) over [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.0/ext/Data/Dumper/Dumper.pm). I wasn't aware of it, but from the looks of it, seems like it's both far easier to use and producing better looking and easier to interpret results.

[Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.0/ext/Data/Dumper/Dumper.pm) :

A snippet of the examples shown in the above link.

```
use Data::Dumper;

package Foo;
sub new {bless {'a' => 1, 'b' => sub { return "foo" }}, $_[0]};

package Fuz;                       # a weird REF-REF-SCALAR object
sub new {bless \($_ = \ 'fu\'z'), $_[0]};

package main;
$foo = Foo->new;
$fuz = Fuz->new;
$boo = [ 1, [], "abcd", \*foo,
         {1 => 'a', 023 => 'b', 0x45 => 'c'}, 
         \\"p\q\'r", $foo, $fuz];

########
# simple usage
########

$bar = eval(Dumper($boo));
print($@) if $@;
print Dumper($boo), Dumper($bar);  # pretty print (no array indices)

$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;          # don't output names where feasible
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;         # turn off all pretty print
print Dumper($boo), "\n";

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;         # mild pretty print
print Dumper($boo);

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 3;         # pretty print with array indices
print Dumper($boo);

$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;          # print strings in double quotes
print Dumper($boo);
```

Comment: make sure you localize any package variables.  eg, `local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 3;`.

Comment: `Data::Dump` is far superior.

Comment: @tchrist: would be great if you could add an answer explaining why, for us noobs.

Comment: @naught101 Because `Data::Dump` is design for legibility. Try it and you'll see.

Answer (score 8):

As usually with Perl, you might prefer alternative solutions to the venerable Data::Dumper:

- [Data::Dump::Streamer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dump-Streamer/) has a terser output than Data::Dumper, and can also serialize some data better than Data::Dumper,
- [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML) (or [Yaml::Syck](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-Syck/), or an other YAML module) generate the data in YAML, which is quite legible.

And of course with the debugger, you can display any variable with the 'x' command. I particularly like the form '`x 2 $complex_structure`' where 2 (or any number) tells the debugger to display only 2 levels of nested data.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) that does not produce valid Perl code but instead a more skimmable format (same as the `x` command of the Perl debugger) is [Dumpvalue](http://perldoc.perl.org/Dumpvalue.html). It also consumes a lot less memory.

As well, there is [Data::Dump::Streamer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dump::Streamer), which is more accurate in various edge and corner cases than [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dump/lib/Data/Dump.pm), it's output is a bit cleaner than Data::Dumper's (no $VAR1), it provides quick shortcuts and it also tries to DTRT, i.e. it will print to STDERR when called in void context and return the dump string when not.

Answer (score 2):

I went looking for the same thing and found [this lovely little Perl function](http://web.archive.org/web/20090730012843/http://netmesh.org/odds-ends/), explicitly meant to generate results like print_r().

The author of the script was asking your exact question in a forum [here](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2006/04/msg83026.html).

```
print objectToString($json_data);
```

Gives this output:

```
HASH {
time                             => 1233173875
error                            => 0
node                             => HASH {
    vid                              => 1011
    moderate                         => 0
    field_datestring                 => ARRAY {
        HASH {
            value                            => August 30, 1979
        }
    }

    field_tagged_persons             => ARRAY {
        HASH {
            nid                              => undef
        }
    }

...and so on...
```

Comment: Couldn't find that 'lovely little Perl function' anywhere on that linked page??

Comment: @someuser yes, link died, I've changed it to archived version