# quivalent function like print_r()

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Perl's equivalent to PHP's print_r()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229168/what-is-perls-equivalent-to-phps-print-r)

is there equivalent  function like  print_r() in perl ,

Comment: When asking questions like this it's useful if you tell us a) which programming language 'print_r()' comes from and b) what 'print_r()' does.

Answer (score 3):

There is the Data::Dumper module (which is core module):

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $var = {'a' => 'Apfel', 'b' => 'Banane', 'c' => ['x', 'y', 'z']};

print Dumper($var);
```

Gives for the above example:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => [
                   'x',
                   'y',
                   'z'
                 ],
          'a' => 'Apfel',
          'b' => 'Banane'
        };
```

which can be eval'ed back into Perl.